# Busca usando between no postrgres

Tags: postgresql

Estou realizando uma busca no banco de dados com o objetivo de retornar apenas as características que estejam entre a faixa de 40 e 100. Mas ao executar o script abaixo ele está me retornando outras características que não não está relacionado com o pesquisado. Aparentemente isso está ocorrendo por que os valores 6.7 e 8.7 estão sendo considerados como 67 e 87 ficando assim entre a faixa de 40 e 100.

```
      SELECT carlis_nome 
        FROM caracteristica
           JOIN caracteristica_lista 
             ON caracteristica_lista.caracteristica_id = caracteristica.caracteristica_id
        WHERE caracteristica.caracteristica_id = 11
            AND CASE 
                WHEN caracteristica_lista.carlis_nome ~ '^[0-9]'
                    THEN TO_NUMBER(caracteristica_lista.carlis_nome, '999999999')
                ELSE 0
                END BETWEEN 40
                AND 100
```

**Ao executar esse SQL está me retornando esses registros:**

[image: Retorno da busca]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está convertendo os valores para um número inteiro, de forma que o postgres está ignorando o separador. Altere a função `TO_NUMBER` para:

```
TO_NUMBER(caracteristica_lista.carlis_nome, '9.99999999')
```

E você deve obter o resultado esperado.

Comment: me retornou isso: ERRO:  estouro de campo numeric
DETAIL:  Um campo com precisão 1, escala 0 deve arredondar para um valor absoluto menor do que 10^1.

Comment: Eu esqueci um detalhe. Qual é a quantidade máxima de digitos que você terá na parte inteira do número? Essa será a quantidade de 9s que você vai ter na parte inteira da string. Por exemplo: 1800 Megapixels, 4 noves => `'9999.9999999'`